# codeigniter form validation always false

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Hello I have tried to look at others but, can't find out why mine is not working based on their code and solutions. If I disable (comment out) the form validation I can get post data to show. But if left in it always comes out at false and no post data is shown. I have auto loaded my model, url,form,text,security, form_validation

in controller

```
// Log in user
        public function login(){
            $data['title'] = 'Sign In';

            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

                $this->load->library('form_validation');


            // validate rules for login cedentials
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

            // if login credentials are not entered (validation is false) show login view
            if(!$this->form_validation->run()){
                $this->load->view('templates/header');
                $this->load->view('users/login', $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');
                echo "Not valid!";
                echo "<br>";
                print_r($this->input->post());
                echo $this->input->post('username');
                echo validation_errors();
                echo $this->form_validation->run();


            } else { 

                // Get username
                $username = $this->input->post('username');
                // Get and encrypt the password
                $password = $this->input->post('password');

                // Login user with model (database)
                $user_id = $this->user_model->login($username, $password);

                if($user_id){
                    // Create session
                    $user_data = array(
                        'user_id' => $user_id,
                        'username' => $username,
                        'logged_in' => true
                    );

                    // set session user data
                    $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);

                    // Set message
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('user_loggedin', 'You are now logged in');

                    redirect('users/index');
                } else {
                    // Set message
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('login_failed', 'Login is invalid');

                    redirect('users/login');
                }       
            }
        } // end function login
```

in view form

```
<?php echo form_open('users/login'); ?> <!-- the action is the controller users and the function register -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">

            <div class="my-input-control-100p">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username" required autofocus>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password" required autofocus>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>

            <br>

            <div class="center_login">
                <small><a href="<?php echo site_url("pages/view/register") ?>">Register here</a> </small>
                <br>
                <br>
                <small><a href="<?php echo site_url("pages/view/forgot") ?>">Forgot Password or User Name</a> </small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: Plain text passwords should nlot be saved as password verifiers. When saving a password verifier just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Better yet use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt`, `passlib.hash` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: with flipped logic, I can at least print out the username and password (if($this->form_validation->run() !== false){)

Comment: It is all about protecting the users and their credentials, not developer convenience. Passwords should never be saved in plain text on the server. With PHP use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php), the pair are secure and easy to use.

Comment: Keep in mind that you shouldn't have more than one `autofocus` form control on a single page

Comment: You get any errors? Put `<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>` above your opening form. Does `if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)` do it?

Comment: <?php echo validation_errors(); ?> doe not out put anything, but ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) will show my post variables. Not sure why

Comment: no, not getting any errors with that, when flipping the logic to "== false" the code ran and showed post echo. Also echo "<br> Validation: ".$this->form_validation->run();  shows that form validation is not returning true or false but 1 or 0

Answer (score 0):

This was the only way I got it to work as it was not giving a boolean but the number representation of the booleans

if($this->form_validation->run() != 0){

Answer (score 0):

I Have Also This Problem First Time.
To Solve This Error There Are Two Method:

**First Method:**

$attribute['method'] = 'post';

echo form_open('users/login',$attribute);

**Second Method:**

form method="post" action="php start echo base_url('users/login') php end"

Conculsion :-
You Are Missed The Method Of Form.